# Python Selenium Login Form javascript

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to login via python CLI using selenium and chromedriver on this site
"http://katalog.iz-region-bern.ch/WebOPAC-Koeniz/account/login"

The Connect/Login is not working. neither with driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-login"]').click() nor  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

Inspecting login/password according to dev tools, there seems to be some javascript action on connect button click the POST command looks like this

[screenshot of POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiDSW.png)

I tried the code below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import os
os.system("pkill chromium-browse")
os.system("pkill chromedriver")

USERNAME1 = "myID"
PASSWORD1 = "myPW"
LOGIN_URL = "http://katalog.iz-region-bern.ch/WebOPAC-Koeniz/account/login"



options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("disable-dev-shm-usage") # overcome limited resource problems
options.add_argument("no-sandbox") # Bypass OS security model
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

#TARGET THE FIRST PAGE 
#Give the driver the starting URL and check you've landed where you should by running an assertion on the text in the title of the pag
driver.get(LOGIN_URL)

assert "User account " in driver.title

#COMPLETE THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD FIELDS
username = driver.find_element_by_id("Username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys(USERNAME1)


password = driver.find_element_by_id("Password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys(PASSWORD1)



#CLICK THE LOGIN BUTTON

#driver.find_element_by_name("Connect").click()
#-> Does not work (Element not found)

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-login"]').click()
#-> Does not work (Element not found)



element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-login"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Does not work either : ("Authentification is invalid") returned on the resulting page

any ideas?

Comment: `Authentification is invalid` this error does not belongs to your code but the username or password is incorrect. check username or password you passing are correct. Make sure you are not adding space before or after the username or password.

Comment: "Authentification is invalid"  is not part of the code, commented. I took it out. The password /Username is correct, I checked it before the '''  #CLICK THE LOGIN BUTTON''' with password = driver.find_element_by_id("Password") and '''print(password.get_attribute('value')) respectively username = driver.find_element_by_id("Username") and print(username.get_attribute('value'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(//*[@id="btn-login"])[2]
```

Your button is actually not unique so use the second xpath.

Comment: That fixed it. Lessons learned: always work with  `find_elements_by` instead of `find_element_by` to ensure uniqueness . The latest two lines of above code replaced with `elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-login"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elements[1])`

Comment: No problem please accept my answer if it helped.